# jTable jQuery plugin why is my MySQL stored procedure failing?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, stored-procedures, jquery-jtable

I am trying to implement a filter in [jTable](http://jtable.org/).  Here is the [jTable Filtering Demo](http://www.jtable.org/demo/filtering).

I used the jQuery code supplied by the demo to sucessfully send POST data to the listAction php script.  I access this data and assign it to the $filter variable.  I also add two wildcards before and after the string to tell MySQL to perform a comprehensive search rather then an index search.

```
    $filter = '%';
    $filter .= $_POST['name'];
    $filter .= '%';
    $startIndex = $_GET['jtStartIndex'];
    $pageSize = $_GET['jtPageSize'];
    $sorting = $_GET['jtSorting'];
```

I then call the stored procedure and pass in each variable.  I removed actual database and procedure name, but I verified they are correct.

```
$mysqli->query("USE data;");
$res = $mysqli->query("CALL proced($startIndex, $pageSize, $filter);");
```

$res returns false here.

Calling Stored Procedures DEFINITELY works as I have other functionalities working this way.  I have other Stored Procedures working that simply return 0 to 9 records correctly. Here is the current Stored Procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proced`(startIndex INTEGER, pageSize INTEGER, filter VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM reports 
    WHERE `new`=0 AND ReportingName LIKE filter
    ORDER BY idReports ASC 
    LIMIT startIndex, pageSize;
END
```

Passing in values in MySQL workbench works and the query returns the correct rows:

```
call proced(
    0,
    10,
    'Art%'
);
```

But jTable fails with "An error occured while communicating to the server."

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by getting an error back from MySQL:

```
if(!$res){
    ChromePhp::log($mysqli->error);
    die('error ['. $mysqli->error . ']');

}
```

Error:

```
Unknown column 'Art' in 'field list'
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)(copied from link):

Try using different quotes for "Art" as the identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”). Otherwise MySQL "thinks" that you point to a column named "Art".

See also MySQL 5 Documentation

So simply by adding single quotes to the passed in String parameter works:

```
CALL procedure('$filter');
```