# Using multiple string delimiters in command causing parsing issues with mysql client / bash script

Tags: bash, shell, delimiter, mysql

I'm trying to do the following:

`OUTPUT=$(su - mysql -c "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = "max_connections"'")`

And execute this via a shell script on the local box... however, I get this returned:
`ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'max_connections' in 'where clause'`

If I just do the command locally on the box, without bash:

`sudo su - mysql -c "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = "max_connections"'"`

I get the output expected... so it's like maybe bash is parsing out my delimiters wrong? [A related question revealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query) that I couldn't use single-quote separators for my `variable_name`, which looks like what bash is attempting to parse my `"` as?

**Update:** To demonstrate the issue with single-quotes:

```
mysql@gossdevmydb0119.abn-sjl.ea.com:~
-> mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = 'max_connections''
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'max_connections' in 'where clause'

mysql@gossdevmydb0119.abn-sjl.ea.com:~
-> mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = "max_connections"'
+-----------------+------+
| max_connections | 2000 |
+-----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do need quotes for the mysql statement, then you may use `\"`. Look at the difference:

```
echo "mysql --raw -e 'show vars where var_name = "max_connections"'"
echo "mysql --raw -e 'show vars where var_name = \"max_connections\"'"
```

But, please!: Do not try to run such complex commands in one string, it is difficult to understand and more difficult to maintain. Divide and conquer, look at this equivalent code:

```
#!/bin/bash

User="user"
Pass="pass"
Options="--skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306"
MoreOptions="--user=$User --password=$Pass"
RunStatement="-e 'show variables where variable_name = \"max_connections\"'"

echo "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = "max_connections"'"
echo "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = \"max_connections\"'"
echo "mysql $Options $MoreOptions $RunStatement"
```

Which of the three echo commands is easier to read and understand?

Your script command would become (provided vars are set as above) something like:

```
OUTPUT="$(su - mysql -c "mysql $Options $MoreOptions $RunStatement")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper quoting

```
OUTPUT=$(su - mysql -c "mysql --skip-column-names --raw --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=user --password=pass -e 'show variables where variable_name = 'max_connections'' ")
```

quote `max_connections` in `' '` single quotes

The mysql expect quoted string, but bash removes the quoting you have provided

To understand better consider

```
$echo " "hello " "
 hello  
$echo " 'hello' "
 'hello'
```

see the quoting preserved in the second `echo`

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but if you'll look at the linked question... wrapping `max_connections` in single-quotes isn't an option here..

Comment: @MrDuk but the link says to use a different quoting technique? have you already tried this one, if so i may remove the answer.

Comment: Here since you use `"` within another `"` the quoting ends abrubtly causing the error.

Comment: Right, so that's the problem I'm trying to overcome here