# What is the MySql Update equivalent of this?

Tags: python, mysql, list, insert, sql-update

What is the MySql UPDATE equivalent of this ?

```
INSERT INTO items (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s)", (listtitle[0], listlink[0]))
```

Comment: Hmmm... why do you think than `UPDATE` can be equivalent of `INSERT` ever? It is really unclear what is your question....

Comment: When one `INSERT` , it creates a new line, however with `UPDATE`, it edit's the existing line

Comment: But it is not equivalents - it is totally different commands intended for different usage. At least, with `update` you should provide some criteria for choosing records to be updated - not only new values.

Comment: Ah, but i would think that the message has been brought over such that people understand, I do however get your point or different usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
"update items
    set title = '{0}',
        url = '{1}'
  where COLUMN = VALUE
    and COLUMN2 = VALUE2".format(listtitle[0], listlink[0])
```

Replace the words in uppercase with the specific values or otherwise you would update the whole table.

[Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)

---

Try this

`self.cursor.execute("UPDATE items SET descs ='{0}'".format(item['title'][0]))`

instead of this

`self.cursor.execute('UPDATE items SET descs =%s' % item['title'][0])`

Comment: Yeah, did that too. Got an error which i cant seem to solve. 

Quoted from my reply to Gruby: Initially did that, it however results in a `error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Yii2' in 'field list'`
 Yii2 = a item in the list

Comment: Maybe you need to add backticks around the inserted values?

Comment: Tried that after u suggested that link, still gives the same error

Comment: Can you share the part of the code and the table structure with us?

Comment: Ok sure, it's actually a Pipeline code of a Web Crawler. Using Python and Scrapy Web crawler coupled with MySQL.

http://hastebin.com/ajavifedav.py

Comment: Is the problem here: `self.cursor.execute("SELECT title,url FROM items WHERE title= %s", item['title'])`?

Comment: The problem actually lies with line 54.

Comment: I just tried `self.cursor.execute('UPDATE items SET descs = "%s"' % item['title'][0])` Quoted %s, it however only just inserts the last value of the list only, (http://puu.sh/fbiqb/bbb83251e1.png)

Comment: I meant single quotation marks instead of backticks some comments before, but I don't get what your problem is at the moment? You set in all rows the column `desc` to the value of `list['item'][0]` which seems to be 'Yii2'. Your `update` is working as expected or not?

Comment: No it's not, "Yii2' is the last value of the list, eg: list = [1,2,fwef,2,35y,h6h56,test, twenty,yii2]. I am trying to insert the value in order to the respective columns instead of the last value only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69804/discussion-between-christoph-werner-and-charliec).

Comment: Dont mind me asking, how would go one about illiterating through the rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"UPDATE items SET title = %s, url= %s" % listtitle[0], listlink[0]
```

Comment: Initially did that, it however results in a error `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Yii2' in 'field list'
`
Yii2 = a item in the list