# Unknown column `petid` in `field list`

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a server and I'm stuck in a little problem, when I try to run my server I get this error: Unknown column `petid` in `field list` And I dont really know what a field list is, this have never happened to me before.

This is how it looks like when I try to run the server:

[image]

This is how a **PART** of my mysql code looks like:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `salt` varchar(32) NULL,
  `loggedin` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastlogin` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  `createdat` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `banreason` text NOT NULL,
  `gm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `email` tinytext,
  `emailcode` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `forumaccid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `macs` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `lastpwemail` timestamp NOT NULL default '2002-12-31 23:00:00',
  `SessionIP` text NULL,
  `greason` text NULL,
  `tempban` text NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `forumaccid` (`forumaccid`),
  KEY `ranking1` (`id`,`banned`,`gm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `accounts`
--

LOCK TABLES `accounts` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `accounts` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `accounts` VALUES (1,'admin','d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997',NULL,0,'2008-04-26 12:15:30','2008-04-26 12:15:30','2008-04-26',0,'',1,NULL,NULL,0,'','2002-12-31 23:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `accounts` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `buddies`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `buddies`;
CREATE TABLE `buddies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `characterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `buddyid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pending` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `buddies_ibfk_1` (`characterid`),
  CONSTRAINT `buddies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterid`) REFERENCES `characters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `buddies`
--

LOCK TABLES `buddies` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `buddies` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `buddies` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `channelconfig`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `channelconfig`;
CREATE TABLE `channelconfig` (
  `channelconfigid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `channelid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `value` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`channelconfigid`),
  KEY `channelid` (`channelid`),
  CONSTRAINT `channelconfig_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`channelid`) REFERENCES `channels` (`channelid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `channelconfig`
--

LOCK TABLES `channelconfig` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `channelconfig` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `channelconfig` VALUES (1,2,'net.sf.odinms.channel.net.port','7576');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `channelconfig` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `channels`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `channels`;
CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `channelid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `world` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `number` int(11) default NULL,
  `key` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`channelid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `channels`
--

LOCK TABLES `channels` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `channels` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `channels` VALUES (1,0,1,'2062e90b3ea10a86ff666a76c41aa0d9e9d88f4e'),(2,0,2,'5dfc64fff3b07c7c01ebd39706ec3cf3e6c37464'),(3,0,3,'f47ef28d4a014d8de91de9f28ae6fcd52dfb5f77');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `channels` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `characters`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `characters`;
CREATE TABLE `characters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `accountid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `world` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `str` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dex` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `luk` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `int` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `maxhp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `maxmp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `meso` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hpApUsed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mpApUsed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `job` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `skincolor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `gender` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `fame` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hair` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `face` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ap` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `map` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `spawnpoint` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `gm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `party` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `buddyCapacity` int(11) NOT NULL default '25',
  `createdate` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rank` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '1',
  `rankMove` INT NOT NULL default '0',
  `jobRank` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '1',
  `jobRankMove` INT NOT NULL default '0',
  `petid` INT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `accountid` (`accountid`),
  KEY `party` (`party`),
  KEY `ranking1` (`level`,`exp`),
  KEY `ranking2` (`gm`,`job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=30001;

--
-- Dumping data for table `characters`
--

LOCK TABLES `characters` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `characters` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `characters` VALUES (30000,1,0,'Admin',200,0,999,999,999,999,30000,30000,30000,30000,10000000,0,0,510,0,0,0,30000,20000,100,100,0,0,1,0,25,'2008-04-26 12:26:47',1,0,1,0,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `characters` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `cheatlog`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cheatlog`;
CREATE TABLE `cheatlog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `offense` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastoffensetime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `param` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `cid` (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cheatlog`
--

LOCK TABLES `cheatlog` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cheatlog` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cheatlog` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Not a MySQL expert here, but looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query) question and if you're using a backtick somewhere you shouldn't?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've been looking around alot on the internet (alredy saw that question) but I didnt find any solution. That didnt work. (If you look into the code you see that isnt the problem :P)

Comment: Are you getting the error when running the java program? If yes, please include the java code which is referencing this `petid` column

Comment: No I get the error when I'm inside the client server. Not at the start of the 'java program'

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lzXU6BA.png <--- this explains kinda everything (Yes the server im trying to make is a MMORPG)

Answer (score 0):

Your Table 'characters' has a column named 'petid'. Maybe you are performing an 'insert into' query. Check if your query target table is 'characters'. This error usually happens when you try to insert a value in a column that does not exist.

Comment: I tried adding petid almost everywhere, didnt work, that's why it's in characters. I tried removing it now but it didnt work

Comment: Ok, your problem is quote ( ` ) in table names and fields names, you should not use them. see this examples in mysql reference [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html @Mojko

Comment: So you're suggesting that i should remove each single  ` ?

Comment: yes, try something like this : remove quote in table names and in properties names. Use quotes ' in default string/varchar/char values and not in int

Comment: @Mojko have you changed DB Engine ?