# Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column '' in 'field list') zf2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2, and I am trying to delete a data to database, but data can't delete , error **Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column '' in 'field list')**

my view

```
<?php foreach ($this->list as $data): ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
             <?php echo $data->id ?>
        </td>

 <a href="<?php echo $this->url('mif',array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $data->id));?>">Delete</a>
```

my controller

```
public function deleteAction()  
    {  
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $post = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);
        $storage = MiffModel\Storage::factory($this->getDb(), $this->getConfig());
        $user = new MiffModel($storage);
        $del = $user->del($post);

        if($del){
            $success = true;
            $msg = 'Data sudah dihapus.';
        }else{
            $success = false;
            $msg = 'gagal.';
        }     

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('mif/index');
```

my model

```
public function del($post){
        $delete = "DELETE from test where id = $post";
        $db = $this->_db;
        $result = $this->_db->query($delete, $db::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of question [1346209](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query).  Is it possible that `$post` is NULL?  To check that, would you mind including an if statement in the body of the `del()` function?  It would look something like this...  
 `If ($post) { <My Existing Code>}`  Next, - as was suggested in the link -
 try surround the string you are appending into the query with single quotes - `$delete = "DELETE from test where id = '$post'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like somebody has posted an answer in the comment, but it doesn't seem that clear and they're not escaping the string properly to use the $post value.

Here is what I would suggest doing:

**Edited to use best practise**

```
public function del($post)
{
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('DELETE from test where id = :id');

    // Check if there is a post exists, if not throw exception
    if(empty($post)) {
        throw new \Exception('wrong or empty data provided');
    }

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $post);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: And what happenned if $post = ";'DROP DATABASE;'" ? or any SQL injection ? Your condition is not filtering the input...

Comment: Well yep. I only added in the part that answers his question, the **unkown column** error, the rest of it is his code. But I agree the PDO example you've posted is more complete, if he changes the accepted answer to that I'll remove this answer.

Comment: careful in your post, I didn't see first but you missed a closed bracket near the empty test

Comment: He can't move the accepted answer, you can edit yours to fit with good practises.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer is a security breach I propose this :

This solution is based on using PDO.

```
public function del($post){

$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('DELETE from test where id = :id');

// Check if there is a post exists, if not throw exception
if(empty($post)) {
    throw new \Exception('wrong or empty data provided');
}

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $post);
return $stmt->execute();
}
```

- > From this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- > Quote The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted;
  >   the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively
  >   uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL
  >   injection will occur (however, if other portions of the query are
  >   being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).