# unknown column in filed list sql insertion error

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java method in a data mapper, to create a user in a MySQL database.

Whenever I test creating a user I get this error

> Unknown column 'phone' in 'field list'

here is my java method

```
public static void createUser( User user ) throws 
LoginSampleException {
    try {
        Connection con = Connector.connection();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phonenumber, post, adress, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );
        ps.setString( 1, user.getEmail() );
        ps.setString( 2, user.getPassword() );
        ps.setString( 3, user.getPhonenumber() );
        ps.setInt( 4, user.getPostalCode() );
        ps.setString( 5, user.getAddress() );
        ps.setString( 6, user.getRole() );
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet ids = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        ids.next();
        int id = ids.getInt( 1 );
        user.setId( id );
    } catch ( SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
        throw new LoginSampleException( ex.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

It might be a syntax error, but I'm not sure why i get this error, I have double checked all fields to make sure  that everything is typed correctly.

EDIT:

here is my SQL-script that creates the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`password` BLOB NOT NULL,
`phone` INT(16) NOT NULL,
`post` INT(8) NOT NULL,
`adress` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`role` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'customer',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1;
```

Comment: You mean `phonenumber` ? What is the `Users` table look like ?

Comment: Describe the db table as well

Comment: First try to run the query directly to the db

Comment: Also, add the stack trace of this exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)

Comment: i haved added the sql script. @yash not a duplicate, since this is an insert method.

Comment: look at the answer of that question, if they don't work, thne post.

Comment: i have thanks @yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to column name is not matching at both the places.
you have used column name `phone` in database. 
and you are using `phonenumber` in your java query, so it will not match with your database.
So just change this

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phonenumber, post, adress, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

**To**

```
 String SQL = "INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phone, post, adress, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

it will work for sure, if you are still getting error , then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Your table have a column `phone` but you are using `phonenumber` in your query.

```
"INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phonenumber, post, adress, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Use instead :

```
"INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phone, post, adress, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable possibility to me.

Comment: The first version of the answer, it was mostly "what could be" and not based on facts. No worries @Syn ;-) I don't hunt reputation.