# how to solve unknown where class error 1054 ( at error number)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm implement select query in codeigniter application.

But it shows the below error.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Ak3456' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Ak3456` IS NULL

Filename: C:/wamp/www/application/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

My select query is

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('table',$number);
```

Please any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter **select** query structure is below,

> $this->db->get_where('table_name',['feild_name'=>'value']);

So you can provide **where** data as in **array type**

For example,

> $data = $this->db->get_where('table',array('feild_name' => $number));

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax is

```
// replace table with your table name and field_name with for which value  
//you want to search for Ak3456
$data = $this->db->get_where('table',['field_name' => 'Ak3456']);
```

[Doc link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=get_where#CI_DB_query_builder::get_where).

**Syntax**

```
get_where([$table = ''[, $where = NULL[, $limit = NULL[, $offset = NULL]]]])
```

Parameters

- $table (mixed) – The table(s) to fetch data from; string or array
- $where (string) – The WHERE clause
- $limit (int) – The LIMIT clause
- $offset (int) – The OFFSET clause

Returns: CI_DB_result instance (method chaining)

Return type: CI_DB_result