# In this way can i declare column name in MYSQL (first-name)

Tags: mysql

In this way can I declare column name in MYSQL (first-name) and there is error occurring:

> Error: INSERT INTO saltlogin (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 'email')
>   Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'

Comment: Is the column name is first-name or first_name ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)