# Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query (stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I keep getting MySQL error #1054 when im call my stored procedure

Im tried to give fulll name for column "id" (dbName.tableName.columnName) but the error is:

> Unknown column 'dbName.tableName.columnName' in filed list.

And same for `tableName.columnName`

```
delimiter $$
create procedure `bond` (m varchar(150))
begin 
update returned 
set returned.sale_id = sale.id
where returned.mark = m and returned.sale_id is null;
end $$
delimiter
```

Comment: `set returned.sale_id = sale.id` set `returned.sale_id` to What? What is `sale.id` you have not selected that or passed it as a parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query)