# Unknown Column X in field list

Tags: sql, database

I have an "unknown column in field list" error in my sql query that I cannot figure out. I read there could be hidden characters so I manually typed and ensured the column names are correct. I tried different queries which worked fine. In this case Query 1  can query the table and columns but Query 2 errors out with `Unknown column 'rec.ID' in field list`

Query 1:

```
SELECT rec.`ID` FROM rec; // works fine
```

Query 2:

```
// error 
SELECT 
    rec.`ID`,
    rec.`Status Type`, 
    lender.`ID`,
    lender.`Cost Per`
FROM 
    ( SELECT rec.`ID`, rec.`Status Type` FROM rec) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT lender.`ID`, lender.`Cost Per` FROM lender) AS T2
ON T1.`ID` = T2.`ID`
WHERE rec.`Lead Type` = "Activated"
```

Comment: you do not specify what db you are using, but this is a more mature question with a ton of helpful answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    T1.`ID`,
    T1.`Status Type`, 
    T2.`ID` as ID2, -- to keep column names different
    T2.`Cost Per`
FROM 
    ( SELECT rec.`ID`, rec.`Status Type` FROM rec) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT lender.`ID`, lender.`Cost Per` FROM lender) AS T2
ON T1.`ID` = T2.`ID`
WHERE T1.`Lead Type` = "Activated"
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I now realize the outter SELECT must refer to the alias assigned to the table in the subqeury. This works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subqueries:

```
SELECT r.`ID`, r.`Status Type`, l.`ID`, l.`Cost Per`
FROM rec r JOIN
     lender l
     ON r.`ID` = l.`ID`
WHERE r.`Lead Type` = 'Activated';
```

Notes:

- Although it doesn't shouldn't a difference, some databases materialize subqueries which incurs additional overhead.
- Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Use single quotes for string and date constants.
- There is no need to select `l.ID`.  It is the same as `r.ID`.